# PHP arithmetic operator ++

Tags: php, math, operators

Why can I only increment by one and not by other value?

```
if(5++$var == 10){ ... }
```

shows a parse error

Comment: What would you expect to happen in this case?

Comment: to set $var to $var + 5 and get it

Comment: you could do `($var+=5)==10`, but I wouldn't recommend it. It's not very clear to read.

Comment: btw are you sure you want to increment?

Comment: yes, just like ++$var, but with 5 :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `+=` operator for this.

```
$var += 5
```

Comment: Erm ... does this mean "Add the value of `var` to `5` and store the result back in `5`?  (Reminds me of an old FORTRAN book that explained why it's better to use the constant PI instead of its numerical value: "in case the value of pi should change.")

Comment: well I'm not surprised I see this for `php` tagged questions on a daily (or even hourly) basis

Answer (score 2):

You can use the compound assignment operator:

```
($var+=5) == 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can increment by another value, the syntax is just different:

```
$x += 5
```

`5++` however is not valid. The `++` operator increments a *variable* and returns the old value of that variable. `5` is a constant; you can't modify it.

You either want `5 + $var == 10` or, more clear: `$var == 5`

Answer (score 2):

It's showing a parse error, because it's a parse error. (As it's written, you're attempting to post-increment the numerical value 5, etc.)

If you're attempting to check if 5 + `$var` is equal to 10 use:

```
if(($var + 5) == 10) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because ++ is an increment operator that increments exactly by one.

```
$var += 5
```